# How can I get Eclipse to save preferences?

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to change the Formatter that my eclipse Java workspace uses. I change it but whenever I open Eclipse again I have to change it again. How can I make it save these preference changes?

I know it isn't being saved because whenever I save edits after re-opening Eclipse it formats the code according to the old Formatter.
Old:

```
    try
    {
        Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(character));
        return new FunctionType(null, Type.NUMBER);
    }
```

New:

```
try {
    Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(character));
    return new FunctionType(null, Type.NUMBER);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
```

Comment: How do you verify that they aren't changed? Where is the workspace being kept?

Comment: @nitind Updated question. It is being kept in a subfolder of the Eclipse install folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I enabled project specific settings  and changed the Formatter there which isn't ideal but it saves at least.

Answer (score 2):

Copy this directory into your workspance.
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings

OR

This problem will occur everytime when you change your workspace, so you have to import your prefrences and export it to your new workspace
To export preferences click file->export->general->preferences
And then import it as click on file then import and chose your file like above

Comment: Where would I find the directory that I am supposed to copy into the workspace?

Comment: Just export your preferences and import that directory into your new workspace and everytime when you change your workspace

Comment: .medata is a hidden directory inside every workspace. You need to copy this directory from your old workspace to your new workspace to preserve your settings

Comment: There's only one workspace that I'm using. I'm just trying to switch the Formatter from my own to the Java Conventions preset.

Comment: Try one of the two methods above in the answer